# ORDER BY complex

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I've a mysql_query: `select * from table ORDER BY v1, v2 ASC`

Can be made a query to sort `v1`, `v2` as below ?

```
+---------------+-----------------------+------+-----+
| id            | name                  | v1   | v2  | 
+---------------+-----------------------+------+-----+
| 1             | a                     | 1    |  A  |
| 2             | a                     | 2    |  B  |
| 3             | a                     | 3    |  C  |
| 4             | a                     | 1    |  A  |
| 5             | a                     | 2    |  B  |
| 6             | a                     | 3    |  C  |
| 7             | a                     | 1    |  A  |
| 7             | a                     | 2    |  B  |
| 7             | a                     | 3    |  C  |
+---------------+-----------------------+------+-----+
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54285/6/0)

Comment: yes it can be made to sort

Comment: how? can you post for me a example ?

Comment: you can't get this with ORDER BY and only using v1 and v2

Comment: Maybe you should give a better example, because in this case you could `ORDER BY id, v1` or `ORDER BY id, v2` ... they'd be the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another column to sort like that. You have to tell MySQL why ids 1,2,3 come before 4,5,6. If you have another column that is e.g. 1 for 1,2,3, 2 for 4,5,6 etc, you can sort with:

```
ORDER BY missing_col, v1, v2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Select id, name, v1, v2, (v1 + ASCII(v2)) as mySum
from table
order by mySum
```

ASCII http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_ascii

Comment: MySQL is using Transact-SQL? new to me

Comment: @SirRufo `TSQL` is language for `MSSQL Server`

Comment: @KuyaJohn sorry, i forget to place an ironic tag ;o)

Comment: but it will not sort as asked

Comment: Yup, it wont. I'll remove my answer. Thank you both

Comment: Just `ORDER BY v1 + ASCII(v2)` will do, but at this point the question is too unclear to know if that's what OP meant.